# Design of power input protection on NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX (dev kit)

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet, circuit-protection, analysis

When looking at the schematics of NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX developer kit, they use a P-channel MOSFET (AONR21357) before bringing power to a buck converter (TPS53015, not represented below). What is the purpose of this MOSFET? What protection does it provide?

Thank you in advance.

**Schematic (screenshot):** Following on from an answer by andy_aka, left is power input (DC jack) and right goes to the load (TPS53015 on VDD_DCIN)

[image: schematic]

**Documents:**

- [Datasheet AONR21357](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AONR21357.pdf)
- [Datasheet TPS53015](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS53015)
- [NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX schematics](https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-xavier-nx-developer-kit-carrier-board-design-package-p3509-a01) page 7 and 8 are relevant. An NVIDIA account required to download the archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the answer. It is an active inrush current limiter. We suspect it protects from inrush current caused by decoupling capacitors in front of the buck converter.

The MOSFET is slowly turned on by V<sub>gs</sub> going from 0 to -V<sub>in</sub>/2 in 3*RC/2=150 ms. The equation for V<sub>gs</sub> is: $$V_{gs}(t) = \frac{V_{in}}{2}(e^{\frac{2t}{RC}}-1)$$
where:

- V<sub>gs</sub> is the voltage accross gate and source terminals
- V<sub>in</sub> is the input voltage
- R represents R181 and R182 in the original question
- C represents C168 in the original question

Simplified schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3uFc8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> *What is the purpose of this MOSFET? What protection does it provide?*

It's used to protect a vulnerable circuit against a power supply reversal on node VDD_DCIN. This is a common circuit/method used on many circuits and you'll find plenty of examples if you google it. Here is an example of a few: -

[image]

Picture obtained by searching for [p channel mosfet reverse protection](https://www.google.com/search?q=p+channel+mosfet+reverse+protection&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908&sxsrf=APq-WBu_OgqgBKO0mlp-uCCObtrqaXC42Q:1644326510541&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIqLjMmfD1AhWGT8AKHZpKDtMQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1290&bih=726&dpr=1.25) and viewing images.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it. The MOSFETs in the pictures you sent have their source toward the load (it is the other way around in the NVIDIA design). And the control circuit is also different in NVIDIA design. I'm not sure how they relate then?

Comment: @Marmoz I have to conclude that they have either screwed up in their design or there are other circuits that you have not shown in your picture that rely on some kind of disconnection when the incoming power isn't present. As for which end is load and which is power source, your picture gives no clue.

Comment: Good point, I added a comment in the initial post to specify input and load. What do you mean that they could rely on some disconnection when the incoming power isn't present? Btw, the wire going toward the top, and the one toward the bottom, they go to not populated footprints.

Comment: @Marmoz how would I be able tell that from your drawing?